# Enum with negative/gap value in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have a problem with enum in Java. I have an enum that starts from `-1`:

```
    public enum AipType {
        Unknown(-1),
        None(0),
        AipMod(1),
        AipNoMod(2);

        private final int id;
        AipType(int id) {this.id = id;}
        public int getValue() {return id;}
    }
```

The problem is when I use this code to initialize a var of `AipType`

```
AipType at = AipType.getValues()[index];
```

where `index` is a number in the interval `[-1,0,1,2]` the `-1` mess up the value.
i.e. 0 returns Unknown, 1 returns AipMod and 2 returns AipNoMod.

I used this implementation because I need to set manually the numeric value for each enum case. In other case I have a gap beetwen the values so I have the same problem: I cannot use `values()` and then access with `[ ]`.

I tried to initialize in this way

```
AipType at = AipType(index);
```

but doesn't work.

Ideas ? Thanks...

Comment: `AipType.getValues()[index + 1];` maybe?

Comment: "In other case I have a gap beetwen the values" this is a naive solution that works only in this case. I'm looking for a solution that works always...

Comment: Ok, then. Look to the solutions posted as answers. They all look good. Almost :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't know what the `getValues()` method you're using exactly doing. Is it supposed to be `values()`.

Anyway, you can always add a `static` method in your `enum`, which returns the correct `enum` instance for that value, and invoke it wherever you need it:

```
public enum AipType {
    Unknown(-1),
    None(0),
    AipMod(1),
    AipNoMod(2);

    private final int id;
    AipType(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public int getValue() {return id;}

    public static AipType fromValue(int id) {
        for (AipType aip: values()) {
            if (aip.getValue() == id) {
                return aip;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you're invoking `fromValue()` too often, you might also want to cache the array returned by `values()` inside the `enum` itself, and use it. Or even better, a `map` would be a better idea.

Answer (score 6):

Just have a `Map<Integer, AipType>` instead of using `values()`, and expose access to it via a method:

```
public enum AipType {
    UNKNOWN(-1),
    NONE(0),
    MOD(1),
    NO_MOD(2);

    private static final Map<Integer, AipType> VALUE_TO_ENUM_MAP;
    private final int value;

    static {
        VALUE_TO_ENUM_MAP = new HashMap<>();
        for (AipType type : EnumSet.allOf(AipType.class)) {
            VALUE_TO_ENUM_MAP.put(type.value, type);
        }
    }

    private AipType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return id;
    }

    public static AipType forValue(int value) {
        return VALUE_TO_ENUM_MAP.get(value);
    }
}
```

That will be completely flexible about values - or you could still use an array and just offset it appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

`Enum.getValues()` returns an array of the enums based on the definition order in the enum class.

`getValues()` doesn't know about the `id` field or the `getValue()` method you have added to your enum.

What you could do instead of calling `getValues()[-1]` (by the way, you'll never be able to index an array in Java with -1) is to add a static function like:

```
static AipType getAipType(int id) {
    for (AipType a : getValues()) {
        if (a.getId() == id) return a;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("id=" + id + " does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you declare your enum like below?

```
public enum AipType {
    Unknown(-1),None(0),AipMod(1),AipNoMod(2);
    private int value;

    private AipType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static AipType fromValue(int value) {
        for (AipType at: values()) {
            if (at.getValue() == value) {
                return at;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

And instantiate like:

```
AipType at = AipType.fromValue(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ids are completely custom, the only chance you'd have would be to create a map and store the id->AipType mapping there.

Example:

```
public enum AipType {
  ... //enum definitions here

  static Map<Integer, AipType> map = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    for( AipType a : AipType.values() ) {
      map.put(a.id, a);
    }
  }

  public static AipType typeById( int id ) {
    return map.get(id);
  }
}
```

Then call it like `AipType.typeById(-1);`.